# How to loop through child records from firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

My main objective is to loop through all the records from the request table to check whether the user has reqdetails. I tried my way but i did not turn not to be correct and nothing is displayed when i console log it.

My declaration and constructor:

```
  request: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  userkey: any;
  reqdetails: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, angFire: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.request = angFire.list('/request');
    this.reqdetails = angFire.list('/request/reqdetails');
  }
```

My declaration and firebase console that shows a request table with an user key that has a reqdetails.

[image]

My code:

```
openMapPage()
  {


    let process = this.request.subscribe(records => {
// your logic
 records.forEach(record => {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
    var b = snapshot.child(this.reqdetails).exists(); // true
    var c = snapshot.child(this.userreq).exists(); // true


     if(c.child(b).exists())
     {
     console.log(record.$key);
     }

});

});



  });



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your user-id to receive the user data. To insert the userkey into your query string you can use [Template Strings](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html). See by example below:

```
request: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
userkey: any;
userreq: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, angFire: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.request = angFire.list('/request');
  this.userreq = angFire.list(`/request/${this.userkey}`);
}
```

---

To check if the user has reqdetails you could check the following:

```
openMapPage() {
  this.userreq.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild('reqdetails')) {
      console.log('exists');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi i understand that you have to pass the userkey into the variable reqdetails. But still nothings prints at the console.

Comment: i don't understand your logic. Can you use my following code to do? It would make me understand better

Comment: I showed you how I would implement the openMapPage method, what is your question?

Comment: I mean't i don't understand your openMapPage() method. i should able to retrieve the user key that has only reqdetails. Your method makes me confuse

Comment: Then I would recommend you to read the firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: Thank you for the doc. I have tried the following from the doc but still it does not show anything. Please see my updated post for openMapPage